# Barycentric Coordinates in Equilateral Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, barycentric-coordinates

I have an equilateral triangle ABC with vertices (v1,v2,v3) in the cartesian system. Given a point P(x,y) inside of the triangle ABC I have to calculate the barycentric coordinates of point P.

I know that I have to calculate the two Areas in particular Area of triangle Pv1v2 and Area of Triangle Pv2v3 in order to find a, b, c of Point P.

**My problem is in finding the height of the Triangle Pv2v3**. I know the coordinates of the all the vertices described above. How can i find the Height of triangle Pv2v3 ?

Comment: See formula (14) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html)

Comment: If your triangle has one side parallel to the $x$ axis, then things get much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to calculate any areas in order to calculate the barycentric coordinates. Instead, you can reduce it to a simple problem in linear algebra.

The barycentric coordinates of $P$ are the three real numbers $s_1,s_2,s_3$ satisfying the vector equation
$$s_1 v_1 + s_2 v_2 + s_3 v_3 = P
$$
together with the real number equation
$$s_1 + s_2 + s_3 = 1
$$
Assuming that you are given the coordinates $v_i = (x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,2,3$, and the coordinates of $P$ which I will also write with a subscript as $P=(x_0,y_0)$, the vector equation breaks up into a pair of real number equations 
$$x_1 s_1 + x_2 s_2 + x_3 s_3 = x_0$$
$$y_1 s_1 + y_2 s_2 + y_3 s_3 = y_0$$
Together with the third equation
$$s_1 + s_2 + s_3 = 1
$$
you have a system of three linear equations in three unknowns $s_1,s_2,s_3$, which you can easily solve using matrices or elimination methods or whatever you learned in linear algebra.